# Using ASP.NET with language Python

Tags: c#, python, asp.net

I'm trying to get IronPython as Code-Behind-Language. I think it has to be possible somehow.
So my there is a Test.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="Python" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.py" Inherits="PyTest.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

with the Code-Behind-File Test.aspx.py

```
import System

class Test(System.Web.UI.Page):
    def Page_Load(self, sender, event):
        pass
```

Calling the Test.aspx, there's

> Parserfehlermeldung: "Python" ist keine unterstützte Sprache.

(Means "Python is not a supported language") I also tried with Language="IronPython" etc... 
Any Ideas?

Comment: *"I think it has to be possible somehow"* - why?

Comment: Because :D
https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/kb/276494
IronPython is a .NET-implementation. So I think it should work somehow...

Comment: That article is talking about in-page scripts, not code-behind - have you tried getting that first step to work before moving on to this?

Comment: What if you select the language when creating the page (see e.g. http://www.infinitezest.com/articles/ironpython-and-asp-net-installation-and-basics.aspx)?

Comment: Yes I saw this post. But I'm using VS13 and I cannot choose a specific Language (There is VB->create Website and C#->Create Website). This pack also is for VS10 (?) and dotNET 3.5 - I'm working with dotNET 4.5.1 - so shouldn't the possibility exists in 4.5.1 when it was released for 3.5?